# Adding eventListeners makes my geoserver app stop working

Tags: openlayers, event-listener, geoserver

I am trying to use OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo in combination with OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud to retrieve info from my geoserver and show them in a popup window.
This is my code:

```
    var map,wms,point;
    function load() {

        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{});
        wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS","http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
        // overlay layer from geoserver
        point = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'cite:obj_geom',transparent: true},{projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")} );

        // add layers
        map.addLayers([point,wms]);
        map.zoomToExtent( 
            new OpenLayers.Bounds(36.190737, 35.353912,35.150577, 50.274810)
        );


        var infoControls = {
          click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            layers: [point],
            maxFeatures: 2,
            infoFormat: 'text/plain',
            queryVisible: true,
            **eventListeners: {/*
             getfeatureinfo: function(event) { 
                 map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                     "chicken", 
                     map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                     null,
                     event.text,
                    null,
                     true
                 )); 
             }***/
         }
        })
    }; 


    for (var i in infoControls) {
        infoControls[i].events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
        map.addControl(infoControls[i]);
    }

    infoControls.click.activate();
    } // end function


    function showInfo(evt) {
        alert('hello');
        console.log("Hurray!");
    }

    </script>
```

I have placed my *.php file inside the geoserver directory therefore I don't need a proxy to run it. Using firebug I can see that when I click a point a request is made and I get back as a response the feature id. Everything works fine.
But I can not figure out how to show the popup window. 
In internet I found code that uses an eventlistener but my problem is that as soon as I add the evenlistener then I don't get the map. I see nothing on my screen. What causes the problem for this?
Any hint or help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of syntax errors and using the wrong function for what I wanted to do lead to this error. Using Firebug helped me to find all the syntax errors and kill them.